# Cookie problem - cookie's not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys, I'm having a trouble with a cookie.

The error:

> "linhaOS" isn't defined.

I wanna know if the cookie is null in the beggining of code.

```
$("#pApresentacao").click(function _click(){    



if ($.cookie("exibir") == null)
{   
    if ($("#hdLinhaOsView").val() != ""){i=$("#hdLinhaOsView").val()}
    else {i=0}; 
    $.cookie("exibir",1);
    $.cookie("linhaOS",i);
    _apresentacao(i);
}
else
{

    if ($.cookie("linhaOS") == null){i=0}
    else{i=$.cookie(linhaOS)};

    _apresentacao(i);
};
```

The first cookie(exibir) is working fine. But the second is not! How is it possible? It is almost the same.

Could someone help me?

Thks folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't `$.cookie(...)` it's that the variable `linhaOS` is not defined.

```
else{i=$.cookie(linhaOS)};
                ^-------- If you use a variable you have to defined it
                          but this one doesn't appear anywhere in your code
```

So how to fix it? Well I suppose you wanted to use `$.cookie("linhaOS")` once again, and you just forgot to quote it as a string with `""`. So just quote it as a string, that will fix your problem.

Comment: Man, I'm so stupid! I didn't saw that. Thks. I'm embarrassed..rs

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to wrap `linhaOS` in string delimiters.  Change

```
else{i=$.cookie(linhaOS)};
```

to

```
else{i=$.cookie("linhaOS")};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the statement that reads the cookie should be reading the string `"linhaOS"` and not the variable `linhaOS`.